# NPM - staged files not adding to commit with npm version

Tags: git, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

Currently trying to configure `npm` so that when I run `npm version`, it sets the version in package.json, then adds everything currently staged to its commit, and npm docs make it seem like this is possible, but I keep getting the error stating that the command can't be run because my working directory isn't clean.

Ideally, I'd like to not have to add `-f` to my `npm version` command.

My `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "nv": "node newversion.js", /*Creates a changelog and runs npm version*/
    "preversion": "git add -A",
    "version": "git add -A"
  }
```

`npm version 1.4.1 -m "%s -> custom scrollbars"`

-> `npm ERR! Git working directory not clean.`

Manually staging before running `npm version` doesn't work either.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm not super npm- or package.json-knowledgeable so any help would be much appreciated.

In the end, the goal is to be able to run `npm-version` and it stages anything in working directory and adds it to the commit that `npm-version` makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use [package `standard-version`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-version), which does generate a changelog and update the version.

See "[Automatically generate and release a changelog using `Node.js`](https://blog.logrocket.com/automatically-generate-and-release-a-changelog-with-node-js/)" (Jul. 2021) from [Indermohan Singh](https://twitter.com/imsinghk7) (Software Developer at [Ubiq.ai](https://www.ubiq.ai/) | Creator of [ragakosh.com](https://ragakosh.com/search))

> ```
> npm run release
> ```
>
> Running the command above will show the following message on the screen:

```sh
> changelog@1.0.0 release /home/imsingh/Develop/inder/changelog
> standard-version

✔ bumping version in package.json from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0
✔ bumping version in package-lock.json from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0
✔ created CHANGELOG.md
✔ outputting changes to CHANGELOG.md
✔ committing package-lock.json and package.json and CHANGELOG.md
✔ tagging release v1.1.0
ℹ Run `git push --follow-tags origin master && npm publish` to publish
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this to add other files to the commit as well? And the changelog I'm generating is a json file that displays in the app

Comment: @Wubzy not in its current implementation. But nothing prevents you to add other files, then call this library.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help!